# PLay M3U8 on Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, live-streaming

I have been searching for ways to play an M3U8 media live stream on WIndows Mobile using the media framework.

Kindly share any info on this.

Comment: See here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27005883/playing-hls-m3u8-playlist-on-windows-phone-8-1/27026663#27026663

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15562826/can-i-play-m3u8-format-in-windows-mobile/29162414#29162414

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more research i found out that m3u8 is a format supported by APPLE.

Unfortunately we cannot play the m3u8 files on windows phone directly.

Rather we can use the streaming media framework to play .manifest files.
The .manifest files are generated by the SMOOTH STREAMING MEDIA SERVER.
.manifest files are equivalent of m3u8 files. It is also a playlist file just like the
m3u8 file.

SMOOTH STREMAING SERVER, is a part of windows media servies that works on a IIS server.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read and parse the m3u8 file (it's a simple text file). Then stream the parsed Uri(s).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Windows Phone Streaming Media free library, it worked fine for me, there is a [blog post about it:](http://www.tareqateik.com/http-live-streaming-hls-on-windows-phone-not-3ivx-free-solution)

Answer (score 0):

3ivx live streaming  [3ivx](https://www.3ivx.com/technology/windows/metro/http_live_streaming.html) although this is not free

Answer (score 0):

First add reference.

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Microsoft.PlayerFramework;assembly=Microsoft.PlayerFramework"
xmlns:smmedia="clr-namespace:SM.Media.MediaPlayer;assembly=SM.Media.MediaPlayer.WP8"


<local:MediaPlayer Name="player"
               HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
               AutoPlay="True"
               Volume="0.7"
               Source="http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8"
               IsPlayPauseVisible="True">
    <local:MediaPlayer.Plugins>
        <smmedia:StreamingMediaPlugin />
    </local:MediaPlayer.Plugins>
</local:MediaPlayer>
```