# Can i play m3u8 format in windows mobile?

Tags: windows-phone-7, live-streaming, m3u8, internet-radio

Sorry for the question, i don't have windows mobile to test. I am trying to develop a live internet radio application.

The format they stream is in m3u8, i have got SDKs for all other mobile platorms but not for windows phone.

Is there any SDK available for playing internet radio or will the m3u8 format of media supports in default.

Please suggest me. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

By default - no. However, you could use the [HTTP Live Streaming SDK](http://www.3ivx.com/technology/windows/metro/http_live_streaming.html).

Comment: Looks this link is for windows 8 desktop version, can i use this for windows phone 7.0 and above?

Comment: It should be for Windows Phone 8 as well. You'll have to experiment on your own to see if it supports 7.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Windows Phone Streaming Media which supports both Windows Phone 8 and Windows Phone 7, here is a [blog post](http://www.tareqateik.com/http-live-streaming-hls-on-windows-phone-not-3ivx-free-solution#.UZIFjbX-HK0) about it

Answer (score 0):

There is also player framework
[Player Framework](http://playerframework.codeplex.com/)